# gitlab-ci include *gitlab-ci yml does not exist

Tags: gitlab-ci

When using the regular include YML configuration file, an error will be reported, indicating that the file does not exist

```
include:
  - local: .gitlab/staging/*.gitlab-ci.yml
```

Find the error in your .gitlab-ci.yml :
Local file `.gitlab/staging/*.gitlab-ci.yml` does not exist!

but，it is normal to import one file

```
include:
  - local: .gitlab/staging/oa.gitlab-ci.yml
```

it works

Comment: Have you tried to quote the paths, e.g. - local: '.gitlab/staging/*.gitlab-ci.yml'?. That's how they do it on the [gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-includelocal-with-wildcard-file-paths)

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes around the path string, otherwise it will not be interpreted properly.

```
# This matches all `.yml` files in `configs` and any subfolder in it.
include: 'configs/**.yml'

# This matches all `.yml` files only in subfolders of `configs`.
include: 'configs/**/*.yml'
```

See, [Use `include:local` with wildcard file paths](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-includelocal-with-wildcard-file-paths).

Comment: @heyden, was this helpful at all?